# How can one make sure the plot frame is consistent?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting some box plots for my data and noticed that although I'm using the same code for making my plots, but I sometimes get plots whose frames are not consistent with the other ones. The only things that change is the plot title and the data and I manually fix the range (`ax.set_xlim()`). For example, see the two plots below:

[image]
[image]

As you can see although the x axis has the same range but the frames are not the same in both plots.

What should I do to make sure I will always get consistent frames?

Comment: please show us your codes. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by frame, exactly? The area outside the axis? The box around the axis? I can't see any striking difference between the two plots. I think it would be helpful if you changed the color of the "frame" to something non-standard so people know what you are talking about.